# Elasticsearch: Aggregation on different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using a specific piece of software to index data into Elasticsearch, but it creates documents like this:

```
{
  contact: +31644488857,
  name: "Jan",
  address: "street 3"
}
```

and

```
{
   person: {
       phone: +31688844499,
       address: "street 5"
   }
   name: "Piet"
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to create a table in kibana, which combines the **phone numbers**, but treats them as a single field. So I do not want to create different tables, or multiple columns for multiple fields. I just want to create a single table which shows all phone numbers, regardless of which field it's from.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I wished I could use a scripted field, but it seems that I cannot aggregate on scripted fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly create a scripted field in Kibana for (`keyword`) strings that you can later aggregate.

Simply go to "Management > Index Patterns", pick the relevant index pattern, create a new scripted field of type string and use the following script:

```
[doc['contact.keyword'].value, doc['person.phone.keyword'].value]
```

This will create a new scripted field that contains an array whose elements will be your phone number fields. You can then visualize that field either in the Discover view or in a terms aggregation in the Visualization view.

Comment: Thanks! Got a lot of issues before so figured it didn't work for me back then, guess I used non-keyword type of fields or something. Anyway it does work now, but I get a time-out constantly on my single-node 20GB RAM setup with 2 million documents... Any tips to speed things up?